# Restrict vertical content within a div

Tags: css, html

I am having trouble restricting a div to house its content vertically within itself. I want the project description portion of the overlay div to restrict its content vertically, and I have tried to resolve this issue two ways.

The first way I tried was to put `overflow-y: auto;` as part of the project description div and this is the result I got:

[image: image of problem 01]

The second way I tried to solve this was by putting `overflow-y: auto;` as part of the entire overlay div and this was the result I got:

[image: image of problem 02]

The issue with the second method is that I want the scroll bar to be able to appear, but I don't want the scroll bar to cause that side bar of information to not be available (or immediately so, it is below all of the text rather than to the side). I think that increasing the size of the div could work width wise, but that would cause it to loose its formatting with Skeleton (which I could rebuild the portions I need to work with this overlay function), but as a novice at web design and building, I figured I would ask and see if there is some obvious solution I am just missing.

TL:DR - I want my overlay div to have another div inside of it which scrolls vertically.

Source Code and Such:

- I am using [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) to help build my site.
- [Here](http://pastebin.com/0Cgp1Dpt) is the html I am using.
- [Here](http://pastebin.com/7qiG94sg) is the part of the css which I added.

Comment: Did you try `overflow-y: scroll;` on the project description div?

Comment: Is your site online, so we can inspect the code pls?

Comment: MattKieran http://i.imgur.com/sM9cWPB.png is an image of what you have asked for. :D

@chadocat It is now online at http://alexanderlyons.net/

Comment: What browser are you usgin? I've tried adding `overflow-y: auto` to `.overlay-container` and it worked fine (the side bar did not move).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the blank `<div>` from below `.overlay-container`:

```
<div class="container overlay-container">
  <h2 id="projectTitle"></h2>
  <div class="two-thirds column project-description"></div>
  <div class="one-third column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: inspected the code too and came to the same conclusion either delete the div or give it a 100% height +1